# How to insert html with innerHtml correct?

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I want to use [ListView](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_split2) in my android WebView and I have created `json` to send my variable to `JavaScript`.It works but when I append html line with `innerHtml` my page like below and I can't see any error on `Inspect Element`

[Image](http://uupload.ir/files/fyfp_capture.png)

Html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getDir()">
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" style="float:right !important">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="dir_list">
  </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="download" data-dialog="true">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini" data-rel="back">حذف</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini" data-rel="back">تغییر نام</a>
  </div>
</div> 
<script>
    function fill_dir()
    {
        return AndroidFunction.list();
    }
    //-------------------
    function getDir()
    {
        var text = fill_dir();
        //alert(text);
        document.getElementById('dir_list').innerHTML = "";
        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        var txt = "<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-inset=\"true\">";
        for (i = 0; i < obj.List.length; i++)
        {
            txt += "<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/letter2.png\"><h2>"+obj.List[i].DIR+"</h2></a><a href=\"#download\" data-transition=\"pop\" data-icon=\"gear\">Download Browser</a></li>";
        }
        document.getElementById('dir_list').innerHTML += txt+"</ul>";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, use `$('#dir_list').html(txt+"</ul>")`

Comment: @Satpal : yes.it's jQueryMobile and I use your line but nothing change

Comment: @Satpal : when I append `<li> ... </li>` manually it's work fine but when I insert automatically everything are destroy

Comment: Do me a favor, can you paste a sample of `var text = fill_dir();`?

Comment: @Drakes : `{"List":[{"DIR":"name1"},{"DIR":"name2"},{"DIR":"name3"}]}`
http://uupload.ir/files/d7tb_capture1.png

Comment: Can you visit this JSBin? I'm running your code and three browser links are appearing. Please comment on the expected functionality. http://jsbin.com/qojetayasu/2

Comment: @Drakes : links in my emulator are appearing but when I append html automatically (with `innerHtml`) it doesn't like http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_split2

Comment: I got it working ;) Let me write up a solution for you k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how jQuery Mobile handles your new HTML elements. JQuery Mobile adds attribute tags dynamically. Since you load your HTML fragments after jQuery Mobile does, poor jQuery Mobile doesn't get to parse and modify them.

Your solution is to simply add `$('#dir_list').enhanceWithin();` right after the `document.getElementById('dir_list').innerHTML = txt+"</ul>";` bit. It's as easy as that! This tells jQuery Mobile to look at your new HTML and process it.

REF: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('dir_list').innerHTML = txt+"</ul>";
```